# unit test FileReader.onload fn with Jasmine and angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I've a custom directive which is used to upload/import a binary file. The directive listens for a change event on an `<input type="file"../>` element.

So now I've a test which triggers a change event, which works fine and do have code coverage apart from the body of `reader.onload()` fn. So, can someone guide me on what to do so that `...onload()` fn is trigger via unit test.

### here is the listener within directive:

```
element.bind('change', function(changeEvt){
  var reader = new FileReader();
  var result = {
    filename: changeEvt.target.files[0].name
  };

  reader.onload = function (loadEvent) {
    scope.$apply(function () {
      result.data = loadEvent.target.result;
      scope.fileSelected({content: result});
    });
  };

  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(changeEvt.target.files[0]);
});
```

### test I've so far:

```
describe('file import', function () {
beforeEach(inject(function ($compile) {
  scope.testOnFileSelected = jasmine.createSpy('testOnFileSelected');
  eventListener = jasmine.createSpy();
  spyOn(windowMock, 'FileReader').and.returnValue({
    addEventListener: eventListener,
    readAsArrayBuffer : function() {
      //return console.log(file);
    }
  });
  elm = angular.element('<div id="testImportBtn"><my-file-select-button id="testFileSelect" caption="buttonText" file-selected="testOnFileSelected(content)" ng-disabled="testDisabled"></my-file-select-button></div>');
  $compile(elm)(scope);
  scope.$digest();
}));

fit('should render the button and be visible', function () {
  var button = elm.find('#testFileSelect');
  button .triggerHandler({type: 'change', target: {files: [{name: 'some.tar.gz'}]}});
  expect(windowMock.FileReader).toHaveBeenCalled();
  //expect(eventListener).toHaveBeenCalled(); Fails 
  //expect(scope.testOnFileSelected).toHaveBeenCalledWith({data: {}, fileName: 'some.tar.gz'}); fails
});
});
```

### Here is a view of code coverage:

[image]

Comment: hi, @Simple-Solution did you get any solution for this? If yes, please update here. I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @aditya I could not get it to work.

Answer (score 6):

You could have add onload function in spy and call directly after fileReader invoked.

```
      spyOn(window, 'FileReader').and.returnValue({
        onload: function() {
        },
        readAsArrayBuffer : function() {
          //return console.log(file);
        }
      });
```

and "it" block you can call onload function like,

```
      var mockedLoadEvent = { //eventdetails }
      expect(window.FileReader).toHaveBeenCalled();
      window.FileReader().onload(mockedLoadEvent);
```

This will call your custom onload function in controller/Service.

complete code below:

```
describe('file import', function () {
  beforeEach(inject(function ($compile) {
     scope.testOnFileSelected = jasmine.createSpy('testOnFileSelected');
     eventListener = jasmine.createSpy();
     spyOn(window, 'FileReader').and.returnValue({
        onload: function() {
        },
        readAsArrayBuffer : function() {
          //return console.log(file);
        }
      });
      elm = angular.element('<div id="testImportBtn"><my-file-select-button id="testFileSelect" caption="buttonText" file-selected="testOnFileSelected(content)" ng-disabled="testDisabled"></my-file-select-button></div>');
      $compile(elm)(scope);
      scope.$digest();
   }));

   it('should render the button and be visible', function () {
      var button = elm.find('#testFileSelect');
      button .triggerHandler({type: 'change', target: {files: [{name: 'some.tar.gz'}]}});
      var mockedLoadEvent = { //eventdetails }
      expect(window.FileReader).toHaveBeenCalled();
      window.FileReader().onload(mockedLoadEvent);
   });
});
```